# How to set Home page menu as active when slug is not defined in admin panel?

Tags: craft3

Is their is any way to set active class to a page when slug is not define?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

craft.request is useful for setting an "active" class based on URL segments without slug.
In your template you can set a slug in twig and then you can run if statement to check what the segment is. Check below example for that.

```
<ul>
    {% set slug = craft.app.request.getSegment(1) %}                        
    {% for entry in entries %}
        {% set destination = entry.linkDestination.one() %}
        <li {% if slug == destination.slug or (destination.slug == 'home' and slug == null) %} class="active" {% endif %}>
            <a href="{{ destination.url }}"><span>{{ entry.linkText }}</span></a>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}   
</ul>
```